# Invoking C++ function from C# passing a void pointer that is type stripped

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to use a third-party DLL written in ANSI C (compiled as C++). One of the functions has the following C++ prototype:

```
tResultCode GetAttrib
(
    tHandle     handle,
    tAttrib     attrib,
    void *      value,
    tAttribType valueType,
    int         valueMaxSize
);
```

Where the arguments of `GetAttrib` are as follows:

- `handle` is a void pointer to an opaque structure within the DLL
- `attrib` indicates which attribute to retrieve from the structure
- `value` a pointer to a variable of the type indicated by `valueType`
- `valueType` indicates the C++ type of the buffer allocated to hold the
  attribute value
- `valueMaxSize` is the number of bytes allocated to variable pointed to by `value`

The `eAttribType` enumeration is defined as follows:

```
typedef enum eAttribType
{
    eHandle,
    eBool,
    eEnum,
    eInt,
    eLong,
    eFloat,
    eDouble,
    eDate,
    eTime,
    eTimestamp,
    eString,     // char *
    eChar,       // char
    eVoid,
    eHandle,
    eFunctionPointer
} tAttribType;
```

The `eAttrib` enumeration is defined as follows:

```
typedef enum eAttrib
{
    eInvoiceNumber, // eString
    eInvoiceDate,   // eTimestamp
    eUnits,         // eLong
    ePrice,         // eFloat
    eDiscount,      // eDouble
    ePreferredFlag, // eBool
    ...
} tAttrib;
```

I declare the unmanaged function pointer in C# as follows:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal delegate eResultCode getAttrib(void** handle, eAttrib attrib, void* value, eAttribType attribType, int valueMaxSize);
    internal unsafe getAttrib GetAttrib;
```

Where:

- `handle` is a `void **` for the pointer to the C++ library structure
- `attrib` mimics the C++ enumeration that indicates the attribute to retrieve
- `value` is a `void *` to the C++ variable
- `attribType` mimics the C++ enumeration that indicated the C++ type of `value`
- `valueMaxSize` is an integer meant to represent the size of the variable pointed to by `value`

My problem is that I don't know how call GetAttrib() from C# with different data types for the `void *` (the `value` variable). Sometimes this variable will be a C++ `char *`, and other times it will be a C++ `int`, and still other times it will be a C++ `enum`, etc

If someone can show me how to properly allocate/populate a `char *` (`eString`) and a `long` (`eLong`) from C# I think that the rest will fall into place (hopefilly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `eString` is a special case, since it's the only variable-length type. The other types are of a fixed size and should be easier to retrieve.

So let's start with `eLong`. This maps to a C++ `long`, which in turn should *probably* map to a C# `int` - but this is architecture dependent so your mileage my vary.

- In C#, an `int` is always 32-bit, and a `long` is always 64-bit.
- In C++, there's [no fixed size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). For all you know, an `int` is defined as at least 16-bit, and a `long` as at least 32-bit. In Visual C++, they're [both 32-bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx) though.

Make sure you know what you're doing and you get the sizes right.

Now, you need a pointer to unmovable memory the unmanaged function can safely write to. As it happens, *value type* stack variables won't be moved by the GC, so you can simply write the following:

```
internal static unsafe int GetUnits(void** handle)
{
    int value;
    GetAttrib(handle, eAttrib.eUnits, &value, eAttribType.eLong, sizeof(int));
    return value;
}
```

Another method would involve [`stackalloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx):

```
internal static unsafe int GetUnits(void** handle)
{
    var buffer = stackalloc int[1];
    GetAttrib(handle, eAttrib.eUnits, buffer, eAttribType.eLong, sizeof(int));
    return *buffer;
}
```

You could use this with a `stackalloc byte[whatever]` if there's no C# built-in type that could fit.

That's obviously untested as I don't have the lib, but it should do it.

As for strings, you'd need a managed array, so you can feed them into [`Encoding.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx). Yeah, you need to know the encoding too. I'll assume ASCII here.

```
internal static unsafe string GetInvoiceNumber(void** handle)
{
    var buffer = new byte[512];
    fixed (byte* bufAddr = &buffer[0])
    {
        GetAttrib(handle, eAttrib.eInvoiceNumber, bufAddr, eAttribType.eString, buffer.Length);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
    }
}
```

As a managed array lives on the managed heap, you need to *pin* it so it won't be moved by the GC during operation. That's what the [`fixed` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) does.

Comment: This approach works well - thank you. Of note, I needed to trim trailing '\0' values in the returned string. e.g.

`Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0')`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: to set a string attribute via the C++ API the following method does the trick

```
internal static unsafe string SetInvoiceNumber(void** handle, string value)
{
    var buffer = new byte[512];
    fixed (byte* bufAddr = &buffer[0])
    {
        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value, 0, Math.Min(value.length, buffer.Length - 1), buffer, 0);
        SetAttrib(handle, eAttrib.eInvoiceNumber, bufAddr, eAttribType.eString);
    }
}
```

Where the corresponding set function has the following C++ prototype:

```
tResultCode SetAttrib
(
    tHandle     handle,
    tAttrib     attrib,
    void *      value,
    tAttribType valueType
);
```