# typedef void* alternative in c#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I am using DLL runtime which is made with C language into C#.
I came across below statement.

```
 typedef void *JCCP_PROPERTY_HANDLE;
```

In function it is being used as:

```
JCCP_RESULT  __JCCP_FUNCTION__ jccpGetProperty(
    JCCP_HANDLE hjccp,
    const char *name,
    JCCP_PROPERTY_HANDLE *phproperty);
```

Now I want to call jccpGetProperty() method in my C# code.
Can anybody tell how can I pass third parameter(JCCP_PROPERTY_HANDLE *phproperty) to function from C#.

I tried with below code but not working.

**Extern Method:**

```
 [DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "_jccpGetProperty", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern IntPtr jccpGetProperty(IntPtr hjccp, string name, ref IntPtr JCCP_PROPERTY_HANDLE);
```

**Usage**

```
IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
string tag = "server.version";
var result = jccpGetProperty(hjccp, tag, ref handle);
```

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Can you give some more details? How did you define the jccpGetProperty extern method in C#? What are the details of "not working"? If there is an exception, what is the message?

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053797/invoking-c-function-from-c-sharp-passing-a-void-pointer-that-is-type-stripped) could help.

Comment: @LPs.. Can you come up with actual code which I need to use. As I am newbie. Cant figure it out.

Comment: I dont know why these questions get minus vote. Nothing is wrong with this question.

Answer (score 3):

`IntPtr` is the correct type mapping for `void*`. The native type `void*` is generally used for an opaque pointer, and that is mapped to `IntPtr` in C#.

Those parts of the p/invoke declaration that we can verify are correct. The unverifible parts are:

- The calling convention. You believe that it is `cdecl`, but we can't check.
- The return type. You believe it to be pointer sized. Again we cannot check. My guess is that a 32 bit integer, `int` or `uint` is more likely. That would make a difference in a 64 bit process.
- The values passed to the function. It's perfectly possible that the function is declared correctly, but you are passing invalid values.

Because you only showed partial code and details, it's hard to say much more. You will have to verify all the parts of the program that we cannot.

I suggest that you start with working C or C++ code and translate that, looking for the first point of deviation in behaviour between that code and your C# translation.

Comment: I explained it already in the answer. Do you understand the concept of what you are doing here? You are mapping two binary interfaces to each other. Every detail must match. Parameter and return value types and values, calling convention.

Comment: return type of jccpgetProperty() function in C is JCCP_HANDLE, which is defined as typedef void *JCCP_HANDLE;

Comment: Do bear in mind also that you get an answer that matches the question. Your description of the error was "not working".

Comment: If all mapping is done correctly this function will return 0, otherwise it returns 17 which is request discarded code. It means we are having problem with mapping. I am sure we are missing something in third parameter. First two parameters are fine.

Comment: The third parameter matches given the info in the question. Furthermore, you asked how to map `void*`, which has been answered. If you need to debug your program, that's a task for you.

Comment: In C code he makes JCCP_HANDLE as type (typedef void *JCCP_HANDLE;). How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Yes, that is the question that you asked, and the question that I answered. I answered that in the first sentence.

Comment: Are you still trying to come to terms with void* mapping to IntPtr?

Comment: Yes, I am still stuck at it.

Comment: You asked what maps to `void*`

Comment: Yes I asked that and IntPtr mapping is still not giving me desired results.

Comment: You have a problem elsewhere. You aren't going to solve the problem by believing that `void*` maps to something other than `IntPtr`. All we can do is answer the questions you ask. We can't write the rest of your code for you, debug code we can't see and so on.

Comment: I understand your point. Your help is appreciated. I filed my query to developers of DLL runtime to check If I am missing some configuration thing.